# c# Cosmos Db check if file exists before creating

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have this method:

```
public async Task SaveAsync(IEnumerable<JObject> models)
{
    foreach (var document in models)
    {
        var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName);
        await _client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, document);
    }
}
```

Which is fine when creating multiple documents at once, but if I have a document that has the same id as one already in the database I get an error:

> Entity with the specified id already exists in the system.

Because the document is actually different I am not sure I can check to see if it exists already.

Is there a way of replacing the existing entity with the new one?

Comment: If it's different, it should have a different ID. Do you want to  update the existing document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DocumentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.upsertdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet) instead of CreateDocumentAsync to create a new document or update the existing one, eg:

```
await _client.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionLink, document);
```

Comment: I actually found this myself, but I will mark as the answer as it worked :)

Comment: Is there a good `create if not exist` for document.  In my case I don't want to update because it will replace the timestamp.  I can always use try/catch individually. but that seems inefficient.